# How does assembly know where to return?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm currently trying to develop an understanding of assembly in the IA32 architecture. I had thought I understood the stack structure until I ran some buffer overflow exploit code, which pushed a return address on to the top of the stack and then returned. The program then, to my surprise, returned to that address I had pushed onto the stack. I had initially thought that the base pointer would be used in returning, as it sits right next to the return address. However, I didn't touch the base pointer. So, how does assembly know where to return?

Thanks.

Comment: CALL pushes the EIP register value on the stack.  RET restores it.  Find another book if yours doesn't explain this, pretty basic stuff.

Comment: The EBP base pointer isn't used when returning. The return address is whatever value is at the top of the stack. The EBP is just a 'helper' which the subroutine can use to make it easier to find parameters and local stack variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ret` instruction just pops whatever is on the top of the stack and uses that as the return address.  Nothing fancy is going on.  If you don't keep track of your stack size and happen to execute `ret` at the wrong time (in a context where the top of the stack isn't the correct return address), you have a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The x86 has several methods to return.

The simplest is the RET instruction. This takes the current address from the stack, put that in EIP and voila.

Because the x86 architecture is a CISC, it has extended features too, so you have a RET with a size parameter. This one is used to replace the basic RET instruction after running an ADD to the stack AFTER THE RETURN:

```
RET 16
-- becomes
RET
ADD 16, esp
```

This allows you to write a single instruction to cancel your parameter variables at the same time you return. The calling convention is very important in this case because the caller is responsible for adding the parameter variables on the stack, and the callee removes them from the stack!

Because the x86 processors come with what is called segments, there is a RET instruction that will retrieve a segment as well as an IP address from the stack. You do not use this instruction in regular programs now a day because the memory model is sufficiently large to avoid it, but it is available. This is called a FAR RET.

Also the Intel processors support 4 levels of protections so the kernel can be protected (not accessible by user's programs) and drivers can also reside in a separate level of protection to avoid kernel spoilage from drivers. The RET instruction can is also used to switch between those levels. Again the information is found on the stack.

Finally, there is a special case too, for interrupt handlers. In a standard program you never see those, which are used in the kernel only. Whenever the processor generates an interrupt, a special handler is called. That handler must return with the special IRET instruction (Interrupt Return). That one too takes the data from the stack, it has more information saved there though, such as registers and status flags.

```
ESP -> +-------+
       |  ...  |  <-- local variables
EBP -> |  ...  |  <-- previous frame pointer (EBP)
       |  ...  |  <-- registers that cannot be modified are saved here
       |  EIP  |  <-- IP address saved by CALL instruction
       |  ...  |
       |  ...  |  <-- parameters to your function
       +-------+
       |  ...  |  <-- local variables of caller
EBP -> |  ...  |  <-- previous frame pointer (EBP)
       .........
```